# Prevent form submit until recapcha v3 finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I am using Recapcha V3 to insert a hidden input in the form with the token. When the form is submitted I check the token in the backend and act accordingly .

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render={{config("recaptcha.key")}}'></script>
<script>
grecaptcha.ready(function () {
    grecaptcha.execute('{{config("recaptcha.key")}}', {action:  '{{$action}}'}).then(function (token) {
        $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                .attr('name', 'recaptcha')
                .attr('value', token)
                .appendTo('form');
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is when a user submits the form too fast and the input isn't yet `appendTo('form')`, the backend receives no token and returns the user back to the form page with an validation error (I prevent data from being sent if the token is not present).

**I can't figure out how to prevent the form from submitting in the first place, until the token has loaded.**

So something like:

If the users clicks submit and the token is not yet loaded do some loading animation and wait for the token and then submit, if the token is present when the user clicks submit just allow the form to be submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to prevent form from being submitted as long as the reCAPTCHA token is not inserted into the form. You can achieve this by using a global variable, which is set after loading reCAPTCHA and checked before submitting the form:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render={{config("recaptcha.key")}}'></script>
<script>
// Whether the reCAPTCHA token is loaded into the form
var recaptchaLoaded = false;
// Whether the user already attempted submitting the form
var attemptedSubmit = false;

grecaptcha.ready(function () {
    grecaptcha.execute('{{config("recaptcha.key")}}', {action:  '{{$action}}'}).then(function (token) {
        $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                .attr('name', 'recaptcha')
                .attr('value', token)
                .appendTo('form');

        window.recaptchaLoaded = true;
        if(window.attemptedSubmit) {
            // As the user already attempted a submit,
            // trigger the "submit" mechanism

            // Note that this doesn't trigger the JS "submit" event
            $("#form").submit();
        }
    });
});

// Add an event listener for "submit"
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    window.attemptedSubmit = true;
    if(!window.recaptchaLoaded) {
        // The reCAPTCHA token has not been inserted
        // Prevent submission of the form
        event.preventDefault();

        // Your button animation logic here...
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: In the  `if(!window.recaptchaLoaded) {}` if the recapcha token has not been inserted, you prevent the form from submiting, how do I submit the form once the token has been inserted? I mean how do I know it has been inserted?

Comment: You set the `window.recaptchaLoaded` variable to `true` when the reCAPTCHA token has been inserted. The `!window.recaptchaLoaded` condition will be false and the form **would not** be prevented from being submitted.

Comment: Altogether, to automatically submit the form, you can use `$("#form").submit()` after inserting the token.

Comment: Yes but what I don't understand is this: what if the token is not yet inserted, the `window.recaptchaLoaded` is false and the `event.preventDefault();` happens . How do I know when the token has been inserted (without inserting it again) and submit the form? I don't want to insert the token again because maybe it will still be inserted but it was not yet inserted when the form was submited.

Comment: So the scenario is : user is fast and submits the form before the input is inserted, at that point the  event.preventDefault(); happens. After, the input is inserted how do I know it finished inserting and do a `$("#form").submit()`

Comment: I edited my answer to check, when inserting the token, whether the user already attempted to submit the form, and submit the form **with the token** if he did. This is done by the `window.attemptedSubmit` global variable.

Comment: This code is the best I've found to intercept the submit click, get the reCAPTCHA v3 token, add it to the form and submit the form. Thanks!